# Fichero CSV creado con PHP no se ve correctamente

Tags: php, excel, csv

El fichero se construye mediante el llamado de una petición asíncrona (ajax), en la cual retorno la url del fichero para poder acceder a su posterior descarga, por lo cual el `content type` de mi respuesta es `application/json` debido al webservice y no `text/csv` *(Aunque realmente no se si definir esta cabecera solucionará mi problema)*.

```
$file = fopen($path . $filename, 'w');
fprintf($file, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF));
fputcsv($file, $headers);
foreach($logs as $log){
  fputcsv($file, (array) $log);
}
fclose($file);
$logs->close();

return $filename;
```

El problema está al abrir el fichero (Con Excel) ya que me deja todo el contenido en una sola celda y no se ve correctamente.

```
1,2,administrador,Admin,Usuario,test@test.cl,,2,test,view,1567541874
```

¿Como puedo hacer que se vea correctamente en las celdas sin utilizar librerías de terceros?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema parece ser más del Excel que del código. 
Sucede que, a diferencia de LibreOffice en el que te deja escoger el separador, Excel tiene un separador de valores que está configurado por defecto en el sistema.

Mira en Panel de Control - Reloj y Región - Región - Configuración Adicional...

El campo "Separador de listas" generalmente tiene punto y coma (;). Si es así, cámbialo por coma (,). 
O si no lo quieres cambiar, en tu código PHP especifica que el separador sea punto y coma (;) para que coincida con el del sistema.

En caso que quieras definir el delimitador en PHP, simplemente agregar el tercer parametro:

```
fputcsv($file, $headers, ";");
fputcsv($file, (array) $log, ";");
```

Comment: Finalmente el delimitador de ; ha hecho que los campos se visualicen correctamente en las celdas. Gracias!